# c# сделать функцию параметром функции

Tags: c#, asp.net, функции, делегаты, параметры

Есть множество функций типа flipImageV. До и после кода в этих функциях должны быть одинаковые строки кода. Что бы в каждой функции типа flipImageV их не писать, хочу сделать одну, куда буду передавать нужную функцию на выполнение...

Вот универсальная функция, куда передаю выбранную функцию типа flipImageV:

```
protected void editImage(delegate func) {
        currentImage.ImageUrl = @"..\images\img0.jpg";
        func();
        photo.Save(@"~\" + imagePath);
    }
```

Функция типа flipImageV:

```
protected void flipImageV(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        photo.FlipVertical();
    }
```

Использование того шаблона:

```
editImage(flipImageV);
```

или

```
protected void flipImageV(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        editImage(photo.FlipVertical());
    }
```

Что должно быть вместо `delegate func`? Как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте просто `Action`:

```
protected void editImage(Action func) {
    currentImage.ImageUrl = @"..\images\img0.jpg";
    func();
    photo.Save(@"~\" + imagePath);
}
```

Вызывать как-то так:

```
editImage(() => photo.FlipVertical());
```

---

Если вам нужно непременно передавать внутрь функцию наподобие `flipImageV`, которая получает два игнорируемых аргумента, можно так:

```
editImage(() => flipImageV(null, EventArgs.Empty));
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Вот, интересно, `editImage(() => flipImageV(null, EventArgs.Empty));` вырубает (проект) IIS и в Webmatrix нужно start ей делать... а `editImage(photo.FlipVertical);` дает `'System.Web.Helpers.WebImage System.Web.Helpers.WebImage.FlipVertical()' has the wrong return type`

Comment: @CodeGust: Тогда укажите **точную** сигнатуру `FlipVertical` и **точное** содержимое `flipImageV`.

Comment: @CodeGust приведенный код корректен. Если сайт и вырубается - то точно не из-за вызова `editImage(() => flipImageV(null, EventArgs.Empty))`.

Comment: @VladD
`flipImageV` вызывается с `aspx` страницы. `WebImage photo = new WebImage(@"~\images\img0.jpg");` в конструкторе. Больше ничего нет.

Comment: @CodeGust: Окей, я нашёл за вас сигнатуру: `public WebImage FlipVertical()`. Тогда проигнорировать результат, обновил ответ.

Comment: @VladD
`editImage(() => photo.FlipVertical());` - работает! СпасиБо!!!

Comment: @CodeGust: Пожалуйста!